# first Android app menu option

Tags: android, xml, menu

My name is robin and i'm totaly new to android development. i've managed to get an menu in the app (yeey).

Now when i het one of these items it doesn't do anything. How do i open a new window? in the app. I know that i need te reffere to something but how where and to what.

This is my menu how it's setup right now

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.usfood.basics.MainActivity" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item android:id="@layout/testpagina" android:orderInCategory="200" android:title="@string/pag" android:showAsAction="" android:enabled="true" android:titleCondensed=""></item>
```

i've tried to read (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) 
but i'm not that good in programming to understand hopfully you guys can help me further.

also there is a new XML called testpagina.xml (this is also the page i would love to open)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.usfood.basics.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="@string/test" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:text ="test pagina text" />
```

all of this has been "programmed" by the android sdk in graphic view

Comment: Hi Robin, welcome to Stack! The way your question is formatted at the moment doesn't fit with stack overflow rules and will likely attract a large number of down votes or be closed very quickly. To avoid this, it's a good idea to edit your question to provide clear examples of your overall problem, what issues you're facing, what you have tried, and why those don't work. Also, it's worth searching to see if your question has already been asked before. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for that.

Hope this is better ??

Comment: Much better Robin! You'll attract loads of good responses now. Don't be put off if it takes a while but do have a read through the other questions here to get a gauge of what's possible and, last but not least, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `onOptionsItemSelected`, and check for `R.id.action_settings`, and perform your action if the id matches.

Example (place in your activity where the menu is created):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // Do your stuff here
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Read the documentation for [Menus](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) for more information

Comment: Hi Kane,

Thnx it worked.

One other question i'm trying to load an image from my server but it doesn't load the image

Comment: If my answer worked, please accept it and post your second question as a new one as it doesn't belong here.